# Execute Ctrl+c in apache mina

Tags: java, apache-sshd

Do you know how to execute ctl+c command in apache mina ssh client? I'm trying to do this like that

```
session.executeRemoteCommand("\u0003", output, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

but i'm getting error that command cannot be empty. Command is trimmed in mina. Do you have any ideas?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Command may not be null/empty
    at org.apache.sshd.common.util.ValidateUtils.createFormattedException(ValidateUtils.java:213) ~[sshd-common-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.util.ValidateUtils.throwIllegalArgumentException(ValidateUtils.java:179) ~[sshd-common-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.util.ValidateUtils.checkTrue(ValidateUtils.java:156) ~[sshd-common-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.util.ValidateUtils.checkNotNullAndNotEmpty(ValidateUtils.java:56) ~[sshd-common-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelExec.<init>(ChannelExec.java:44) ~[sshd-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.AbstractClientSession.createExecChannel(AbstractClientSession.java:384) ~[sshd-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession.createExecChannel(ClientSession.java:183) ~[sshd-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession.executeRemoteCommand(ClientSession.java:275) ~[sshd-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession.executeRemoteCommand(ClientSession.java:246) ~[sshd-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. https://javahowtos.com/guides/108-security/389-connect-to-ssh-server-with-java-using-apache-mina-sshd.html

Using ClientChannel i'm able to sent Ctrl+C command to ssh server.